# Get the details of selected item

Tags: python, django

I have a part table and delivery instruction table (dins). To create a dins, I have to choose a part name. So what I want to do is, after choosing the part name from the dropdown that part's price will be visible in the form.

In the Part table, I have the price value for the specific part name. So during the creation of dins, after choosing such an example part name is X, then the form should show what is the price of that chosen part (X part) price.

Any idea how to make that happen?

views.py

```
def create_deliveryins(request):
    from django import forms
    form = DeliveryInsForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        forms = DeliveryInsForm(request.POST)
        if forms.is_valid():
            product = forms.cleaned_data['product']
            usage = forms.cleaned_data['usage']
            part= forms.cleaned_data['part']

            deliveryins = DeliveryIns.objects.create(
                usage=usage,
                product=product,
                part=part,
            )
            return redirect('dins-list')
    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'store/addDins.html', context)
```

HTML

```
<form action="#" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">

 {% csrf_token %}

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="product" class="control-label mb-1">Product</label>
      {{ form.product }}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="part" class="control-label mb-1">Part</label>
      {{ form.part}}
    </div>

   <div class="form-group">
     <label for="usage" class="control-label mb-1">Usage</label>
     {{ form.usage }}
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You need to use javascript / ajax to retrieve data from the backed and change HTML dynamically upon input of the product name. There is plenty of tutorials available.

Comment: Can you suggest to me any tutorial? if possible @Razenstein

Answer (score 0):

Create a hidden form field that has the part prices for each part.
Use Javascript or Jquery to update the form field for price and show it whenever the form part field is changed.

This would prevent the need for ajax, or additional views or requests.
You would only need to slightly modify your view and template.